# How to create spaces between groups and control size of axis labels in boxplot?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I want to display all values on the x-axis on a boxplot from `min(x)` to `max(x)`.
Sample data:

```
set.seed(4)
x <- sample(1:30, 100, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(1:25, 100, replace=TRUE)
z <- sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(.5, .5))
boxplot(y ~ z + x, las = 2, col = c(5, 7))
abline(v=seq(2.5,60,2), col = "grey60", lty = "dotted") # For orientation
sort(unique(x))
```

Here 6, 27 and 29 are not included in x. Is it still possible to have them on my x-axis, but of course without a boxplot? As B.1 is represented, although no value is available for it.  I would be interested in a solution for both normal boxplots and ggplot2 boxplots.

Additionally, is there a way to reduce the gap between the boxplot for e.g. A.1 and B.1 in a graphics::boxplot, like there is `position = position_dodge(.9))` for boxplots in ggplot2? (Or increase the gap between B.1 and A.2?)

Pretty sure this question occured before, I just might not find the right translation for my problem.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: you need to factor x first. do this x <- factor(x,levels=1:30). as for the gap.. i look into it now

Comment: I ran your example and got all 60 values on my X axis, granted I had to stretch the window a bit. Perhaps just reduce your font size with `cex = 0.5`, it could just be an issue of the letters being too big.

Comment: @StupidWolf It's working! Thank you!

Comment: @RonnyEfronny Hm with setseed you should not have any values in x for 6, 27 and 29. But I'm not sure how setseed works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the distance between the boxes of `boxplot()` we may use the `at` option, which *"defaults to 1:n where n is the number of boxes"*. Instead the default we provide a vector `VEC`.

To control the size of the axis labels we may use `cex.axis`, e.g. `cex.axis=.8`.

## Example

I am using data from the `?boxplot` help page as an example, which does not take up so much space.

`len` is to be grouped according to `dose ~ supp`. So the number of boxes is the `prod`uct of the `dim`ensions of the according `table`. With that information we create vector `VEC` out of a sequence of length `n` (with a some case-wise customization) from which we subtract the desired adjustment from every second element.

```
n <- prod(dim(with(ToothGrowth, table(dose, supp))))
VEC <- seq(1, n/2, length.out=n)*2 - c(0, .2)
# [1] 2.0 2.6 3.6 4.2 5.2 5.8
```

### Plot comparison

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
# without grouping
boxplot(len ~ dose:supp, data=ToothGrowth,
        boxwex=0.5, col=c("orange", "yellow"),
        main="Guinea Pigs' Tooth Growth",
        xlab="Vitamin C dose mg", ylab="tooth length",
        sep=":", lex.order=TRUE, ylim=c(0, 35), yaxs="i",
        cex.axis=.8)
text(.5, 32, "w/o grouping", col=2, adj=0, font=2)
# with grouping
boxplot(len ~ dose:supp, data=ToothGrowth,
        boxwex=0.5, col=c("orange", "yellow"),
        main="Guinea Pigs' Tooth Growth",
        xlab="Vitamin C dose mg", ylab="tooth length",
        sep=":", lex.order=TRUE, ylim=c(0, 35), yaxs="i",
        cex.axis=.8, at=VEC)
text(1.5, 32, "w/ grouping", col=2, adj=0, font=2)
par(op)
```

[image]

This of course might require some case-wise adjustment, but you've got the idea now.

Comment: I used it with my data, it works flawless! Thank you very much!